# Are ditransitives (or tritransitives?) cross-linguistically attested?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology

I'm only really familiar with English and a few European languages, so to my mind it is normal for a language to have a double object construction and/or an NP-PP construction, as in

> John gave [Mary] [a book]

and

> John gave [a book] [to Mary]

English (and as far as I know a few others like German maybe) also have a limited "tritransitive" construction, where verbs like "bet" or "fine" can take three objects:

> John bet [Mary] [five bucks] [that she couldn't spit further than him]
>
> John fined [Mary] [fifty dollars] [for cycling on the sidewalk]

Maybe that's a little controversial. Anyhow, is it "normal" for languages to have either of these constructions? Also, is the restriction on so-called "tritransitives" equally as restricted to monetary terms as it is in English?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you perhaps define transitivity more precisely? It seems you mean "having any verbal complement", not "having a direct object"? So any verb with two or three complements would count? And can you define "normal"? Are you looking for a universal linguistic feature, or what? (You already said many other European languages can behave like your examples, and I'm afraid my knowledge does not go beyond European languages either...)

Comment: I suppose when I say "transitive" I'm just counting arguments, so yes, any verb with two or three complements would be interesting to me at this stage. I suppose I mean "normal" as a stand in for "common", not necessarily universal - I guess I'm interested to see if it's limited to a certain family or area or something.

And thanks, the site is great!

Answer (score 3):

Ditransitives of the English type are very rare. Most languages use either case marking on nouns to signify grammatical relations or polypersonal head-marking. By "English type" I mean that both objects can be passivized. Your example can be paraphrased as "A book was given to Mary by John" or "Mary was given a book by John".

Comment: Passivizability is not a general enough phenomenon to use as a test for anything, and that's not the way Passive works with English ditransitives.

Comment: @Atamiri- if I were looking for verbs that simply take three or four arguments, rather than being stricly of the "English type" as you define it, is that more common? I'm also not aware of polypersonal head-marking, could you give me an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not the case that both arguments can be passivised in English double object constructions (DOCs). Consider: (i) 'Mary was given the book', BUT (ii) *'the book was given Mary'. When both arguments are DPs, only the GOAL can be passivised. In the prepositional dative construction, the THEME can be passivised: (iii) 'The book was given to Mary', presumably because it isn't blocked by a DP GOAL.

Comment: Also, ditransitivity is fairly widely attested cross-linguistically, but of course ditransitive constructions in different languages often display different properties - this can often be derived from independent differences between the languages in question. See this chapter in the World Atlas of Language Structures for further details: http://wals.info/chapter/105,

Comment: The bit of your question on verbs with n > 2 internal arguments is a lot more interesting to me. I don't think there's been much work on that. This paper from Linguistics is the only thing that springs to mind: http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/ling.2007.45.issue-3/ling.2007.015/ling.2007.015.xml

Comment: @Dave Sure, that's more common. Polypersonality occurs in many Native American languages and in NW Caucasian. In Aymara, for example, Qawr churäma "I will give you a llama" qawr is the direct object while the recipient is expressed by a suffix on the verb.

Comment: @jlawler In this case the point is that roles other than patients can be passivized which is very rare. If one writes a formal grammar of English the corresponding lexical rules reveal the role misalignment.

Comment: @PElliott What can be passivized is the primary object. "The book was given to Mary" illustrates how lexical semantics affects passivization.

Comment: Right. In English the Passive promotes the Direct Object to Subject. Period. But what counts as the "Direct Object" is fairly complex. For instance, if Passive is preceded by the Dative Alternation -- which has the effect of deleting the preposition _to_ marking the Indirect Object, and promoting the IO to DO -- then the original Indirect Object gets to be Subject, via Dative plus Passive. It's a marked construction, and it takes two steps.

Comment: @jlawler In light of the theory of Bresnan English has primary and secondary objects (not direct and indirect objects). It makes sense since what's passivized is always the primary object (verbs like give have two subcat. frames).

Comment: Bresnan English is just the way Joan Bresnan thinks and talks about English grammar. Not that many people use that way of talking. The way I was talking was Relational or Arc Pair grammar.

Comment: @PElliott "The book was given Mary" is old-fashioned, but I wouldn't say it's ungrammatical. This kind of passivization fell out of fashion only fairly recently.

Comment: @jlawler Arc pair grammar isn't widely used either :-) I think that simple rules that explain how grammar works are better than complex rules that explain the same phenomenon. If you tried to implement a computational grammar of English you'd see what I mean.

Comment: Neither one is good for computational grammars; those work best from statistical bases, without parsing. Syntactic theories are for description and the design of calculi, not for programming efficiency.

Comment: @jlawler This is simply not true. What's a "statistical base"? There's no such concept in statistical NLP. And what kind of "calculi"? Unification grammars were designed specifically for NLP. No statistical model (if this is what you meant by "base") can be used for accurate parsing (yes, it's called parsing in a stochastic setting too). Rules concerning ditransitives can be directly used in (rule-based) unification grammars efficiently. There are tons of books and papers that describe it. (Maybe I misunderstood your comment since you aren't using common NLP terminology.)

Comment: What is called "parsing" in linguistics and what is called "parsing" in NLP are quite different activities, for quite different purposes, with quite different presuppositions. Rather like the differential use of "phoneme" in linguistics and speech generation/production.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, yes, ditransitives are universal as far as we know. You can take a look at this paper [by Haspelmath](http://email.eva.mpg.de/~haspelmt/DitransitiveOverview.pdf)

Comment: It depends on what you call *ditransitive*.  If you accept "Ich dab dem Kind den Apfel" (*I gave the child the apple*) in German with dative and accusative markings, then it is widespread.  If your definition of *ditransitive* includes the ability to make any of the three nouns the subject as in "The child was given an apple by me" then it is rare.

Comment: @Henry That's not the definition usually employed in typology as far as I've seen, do you know of typological studies where they use that definition? what would be the reason for doing so?

BTW, you misspelled "gab".